# How to dynamically change text color in a flash html5 canvas project

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, flash-cc, htmltext

I'm trying to dynamically change font color in a flash html5 canvas project.
Log_file is my text box name. This is how you use to do it in actionscript.

```
this.Logger.Log_File.htmlText = "<font color='#ff0000' size='-1'>"+myvar+"</font><BR>"+this.Logger.Log_File.htmlText;
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? is htmltext not supported in javascript?

Comment: <font> is obsolete in HTML5. I've never heard of htmlText before.

Comment: maybe you are looking for innerHTML instead of htmlText

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `<font>` in HTML5, use CSS instead.

```
this.Logger.Log_File.htmlText = "<p style="color:#ff0000">"+myvar+"</p><br>"+this.Logger.Log_File.htmlText;
```

Comment: I gave that a shot and it didn't work. i wonder if htmltext inst supported anymore by flash cc in a html5 canvas project type.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this way:

```
elementoDad.elementoSon.children[0].graphics._fill.style = "#ff00ff";
```

Here is an working example:

```
ex1.teste.children[0].graphics._fill.style = "#ff00ff";
```